# Restore SQL db dump doing some sensitive data scrubbing – Any recommended tools?

Tags: sql, database, psql, pg-dump

I want to automate the process of seeding the staging DB with production-based data, but I need to do some data scrubbing to remove sensitive information (billing, contact info, etc).

It seems to be a common use case and I was expecting to find some good practices or recommended solutions for it, but honestly I couldn't find much.

I'm currently using PostgreSQL hosted in AWS RDS.

The alternatives I'm evaluating now are:

- dump using `pg_dump`, restore using `psql` and do some manual modification using python/django script.
- AWS has a Database Migration service that might do the trick (https://aws.amazon.com/dms/)

Do you guys know any other tools for this use case?

Thank you.

Comment: You could put triggers on the staging tables that erase (or otherwise obfuscate) specific columns of data upon insert or update.

Comment: https://labs.dalibo.com/postgresql_anonymizer

Comment: I have the same question and I haven't found any of the existing django scrubbing packages to work well for our use case.